# Huggingface fine-tuning - how to build a custom model on top of pre-trained

Tags: tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers

## Question

Please help understand the cause of the issue below and how to build a Keras model for fine-tuning on top of the pre-trained model from the huggingface.

### Objective

Create a custom model for DistilBERT fine tuning on top of [TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/distilbert.html#tfdistilbertforsequenceclassification) from Huggingface.

#### Input shape to the model

From the shape of the tokenizer output, I assumed it is `(2, None, 256)` as `[input_ids, attention_mask]` would go into the model.

The output of the tokenizer.

```
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizerFast
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

max_sequence_length = 256
tokens = tokenizer(
    " ".join(["token"] * max_sequence_length), 
    truncation=True,
    padding=True,
    max_length=max_sequence_length,
    return_tensors="tf"
)
print(tokens)
---
{
  'input_ids':      <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 256), dtype=int32, numpy=array([[  101, 19204, 19204, 19204, 19204, 19204, 19204, 19204, 19204, ...]], dtype=int32)>, 
  'attention_mask': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 256), dtype=int32, numpy=array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...]], dtype=int32)>
}
```

#### Pretrained Model

```
model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
for layer in model.layers:
    if layer.name == "distilbert":
        layer.trainable = False
model.summary()
---
Model: "tf_distil_bert_for_sequence_classification_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
distilbert (TFDistilBertMain multiple                  66362880  
_________________________________________________________________
pre_classifier (Dense)       multiple                  590592    
_________________________________________________________________
classifier (Dense)           multiple                  1538      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_99 (Dropout)         multiple                  0         
=================================================================
Total params: 66,955,010
Trainable params: 592,130
Non-trainable params: 66,362,880
```

### Custom model

Added a Keras Dense layer on top of the pretrained model using Sequential.

```
seq = Sequential([
   model,
   Dense(
       name="output_softmax", 
       units=2, 
       activation="softmax"
   )
])
seq.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
)
```

## Problem

[The base Layer class](https://keras.io/api/layers/base_layer/#layer-class) says build method creates the weights.

> build(self, input_shape): This method can be used to create weights that depend on the shape(s) of the input(s), using add_weight(). **call**() will automatically build the layer (if it has not been built yet) by calling build().

Run the method but got the error.

```
seq.build(input_shape=(2, None, max_sequence_length))
---
...
ValueError: You cannot build your model by calling `build` if your layers do not support float-type inputs. Instead, in order to instantiate and build your model, `call` your model on real tensor data (of the correct type).
```

As per the error message, feed the tokenizer output to the model and got another error.

```
seq(tokens)
---
TypeError: Failed to convert 'TFSequenceClassifierOutput(loss=None, logits=TensorShape([1, 2]), hidden_states=None, attentions=None)' to a shape: ''logits''could not be converted to a dimension. A shape should either be single dimension (e.g. 10), or an iterable of dimensions (e.g. [1, 10, None]).
```

## Envirionment

```
python --version
---
Python 3.7.10

print(tf.__version__)
---
2.5.0

print(transformers.__version__)
---
4.8.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using Sequential or build method did you try the Keras Functional API?-(I have tried and worked with other pre-trained models) s.a:- (a pesuedo code)

```
def custom():
   x=Input(shape=(256,))
   y=Input(shape=(256,))
   out=distilbertlayer([x,y])
   out=Dense(2,activation='softmax')(out)
   mod=tf.keras.models.Model([x,y],out)
   return mod

custommodel=custom()
```

Here, in the given info. I think the error is due to wrong type of output passed to the custom Dense layer. As a suggestion, you could try passing different output from the distilbertlayer to the custom dense layer, like

```
out=distilbertlayer([x,y])
out=Dense(2,activation='softmax')(out[:,0])
```

However, first the output format of the distilbertlayer should be understood.